# {exec} cause Conky to stop

Tags: conky

I wanted to add mpd informations to my conky and therefore I created a script which role is to get the cover from ID3 tags

This script is called using the {exec 'path'} command

My probleme is that since I added this feature, my conky refuses to stand on his own :

If I launch it from a terminal using

```
conky -c `path.conkyrc` &
```

it will stop when closing the terminal. I tried using the -d option as well

I also tried to launch it at startup with a sh script run at startup : It works well at first but if I open a terminal, conky will close with the terminal i openned ... strange

removing the call to {exec 'path'} solves everything so it is clearly the problem origin

For the record, the script i am using is

```
#!/bin/sh
MPD_MUSIC_PATH="/media/Media/Music"
TMP_COVER_PATH="/tmp/mpd-track-cover"
exiftool -b -Picture "$MPD_MUSIC_PATH/$(mpc --format "%file%" current)" > "$TMP_COVER_PATH" &
```

Comment: Does Conky really close or did it simply go under the root desktop window? When Conky "closes" what do you get with `pgrep conky`?

Comment: ps -A | grep conky tells me it's still running. it must do under the root destop window then

Comment: What do you have `own_window` and `own_window_type` set to?

Comment: own_window yes

own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager

own_window_argb_visual yes

own_window_argb_value 102

own_window_type desktop

Comment: Changing thos to the settings of my "main" conky solved the problem, sorry

Comment: How about answering your own question, then?

Comment: cant yet, will do it as soon as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue wasn't conky closing but it going behind everything, including the wallpaper.

Changing the window settings solved the problem:

```
own_window yes
own_window_type normal
own_window_transparent no
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_type normal
own_window_class conky-semi
own_window_hints undecorate,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below
own_window_argb_value 128
own_window_colour 000000
```